# How to access an XML value in Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I'm receiving an XML response from an HTTP GET request which I need a specific value from. I transformed it in an JavaScript object. How can I access it's values, for example the CompName?
I thought I can use the function node, but couldn't figure out, how exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Debug sidebar, when you hover over an message element, a set of buttons appears on the right-hand side.

The first of these, when clicked, will copy the path to the selected element, relative to the `msg` object. That will help you figure out the path you need for any particular element

In this instance, you'll find the `CompName` in the screenshot you've shared is:

```
msg.payload.feed.entry[0].content[0]['m:properties'][0]['d:CompName'][0]
```